# Universal solution for a steady state vector [$3\times3$ matrix]

Tags: matrices

I want a solution for $i,j$ and $k$ in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ for which:

[image]

I did it for a $2\times2$ matrix, but my way didn't work on this one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to ask for. Could you share the motivation behind this question?

Comment: Perhaps looking up the theory behind this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors You are solving the same basic equation $A \vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$ for $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: The motivation is the steady state probability for markov chains

Answer (score 1):

It may help to rewrite the equation as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a-1 & b & c\\
d & e-1 & f\\
g & h & i-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
i\\j\\k
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$